# How to create a general class for other class can have the same model as well

Tags: python, django, class

I am new to Python and Django platforms. I am trying to design a general class so that other classes can use the general class to create the same model type. To explain better, I give an example

Let's say my general class is

```
class Person(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
 lastname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
 job=models.CharField(max_length=20)
 salary=models.IntegerField()
```

I want to have a exactly same table with Person class for each person that I create.

In my mind is something like that....

```
Class Person1(models.Model) 
Person()
Class Person2(models.Model) 
Person()
```

So, thus each person table will have same model type with Person class. Could you please help me how to do that? OR Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? You can store multiple 'persons' in the original `Person` class.

Comment: For the love of all that is good and holy, read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance You're wasting our time and yours with a question like this.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: that seems needlessly harsh...

Comment: Not really. The goal here should not be to spoon-feed knowledge to people. Things like running a simple Google search or actually taking 5 seconds to see if the documentation might happen to mention what you're about to ask is the *very least* to ask of someone before coming here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want or why you want that, but, I think the answer to your question is to use an [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

Example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   job = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   salary = models.IntegerField()

   class Meta:
       abstract = True


class Person1(Person):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, you understood well.But, I just want to make sure that What should I write for Person1 to have exactly same fields as the Person class?

Comment: In my example, no table will be created for `Person`, because `abstract` is `true`. But one table will be created for `Person1` and this table will the 4 fields (name, lastname, job and salary) of the base class (Person). You can add more fields to `Person1` if you need it. But if you `Person1` exactly like `Person`, you only need to replace my "..." by `pass`. Read the docs...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is a basic understanding of how models in django work.

A model in django is the representation of a *table* in the database. In this table, you can store multiple rows. Each field you write, is a column in this table.

As you have a model *Person* - django will create a table in the database with the columns that you defined in your *Person* class. In this table, you can add many "person" items.

You don't need to create additional models for storing *the same stuff* that you have already described in the *Person* model.

Inheritance is an advanced concept in django models and will only lead to problems later. I suggest that you go through the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) step by step as it explains how to use the django Object Relational Model (ORM) - the models.

Eventually, you will realize that to store multiple "person", you just need to do this:

```
personA = Person()
personA.name = 'John'
personA.lastname = 'Smith'
personA.job = 'Chef'
personA.salary = 130
personA.save()

personB = Person(name='Homer',lastname='Simpson',job='Donut Eater',salary=100)
personB.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to create two tables(PersonB and PersonA) in model.py before doing that, Right ?

Comment: You only need to create two tables if you are storing different information; there is no need to duplicate a table otherwise.